# QueryTable authentication

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have a VBScript which gets a data into Excel sheet through `QueryTables`. The script works fine, but the URL is a server which requires a basic authentication. So when the script runs the login pops up asking username password. Is there anyway to give this username and password programatically.

My QueryTable goes like this:

```
Set objWeb = wks.QueryTables.Add(URL,wks.Range("A1"))
With objWeb
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebTables = sWebTable
    .Refresh False
    .SaveData = True 
End With
```

Help me out...

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible. See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14088474/1630171).

Comment: But httprequest can it be used for a asp based page pls can u show an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [XMLHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453379.aspx) might look like this:

```vbs
url = "http://www.example.org/"
credentials = "username=jsmith&password=foobar"

Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
req.open "POST", url, False
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.send credentials

If req.Status = 200 Then
  html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
  html.write req.responseText
  'do stuff with HTMLDocument object
End If
```

You need to change `url` to the actual URL and adjust `credentials` according to what the server requires. Tools like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) will help you find out what the credentials string must look like.

If you write `responseText` to a [`HTMLDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) object, you can work on the tags with the usual methods, like `getElementById()` or `getElementsByTagName()`.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, this method is way better and have lot of options. but the response text from the result, is simply the source code of the page. Is there any way I can get the value from the html tags. currently it is stored in a string and it is full of nested tables so it is very difficult to get specific data.

Comment: Create an `HTMLFile` object and load `responseText` into that object. See updated answer.