# Batch script/PowerShell advanced conditionals implementation

Tags: windows, authentication, powershell, batch-file, vbscript

My question is in regards to how I should go about implementing a batch script/PowerShell cmdlet on Windows that does the following:

When a browser window is open that has the window/page title "Blank" then send the "tab" key, send login credentials to text boxes on webpage and then send the "enter" key.

I found this article ([Automatic login to a website on windows 7/Chrome via batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204623/automatic-login-to-a-website-on-windows-7-chrome-via-batch-file)) about sending login credentials in a web browser, which is very similar to what I want to do, however I want the script to ONLY run if the browser is already open and has a specific value in the window title. This is for an authentication system for the network running on my server that asks me to re-login every 30 days, and will open up a browser window automatically when it needs me to login. So, when it opens the window, I want the script to be able to automatically login for me. Since the server is unattended (GUI wise), I want the re-authentication to occur automatically. My plan would be to have this set as a scheduled task and have it run nightly, to verify that the system is still authenticated. If the system is not authenticated, I want the batch file/cmdlet to login for me.

I did some research and found information about using conditions for batch files, but I couldn't find any information about how I would use the window title or any other program attribute to base my conditional off of.

People have suggested using PowerShell, so I am totally open to that as well if you have a recommendation for implementation via that route.

Please let me know if you need any further information, or have any questions.

Comment: The best way to do this would be to do it with PowerShell.

Comment: In other words, **don't use BATCH for this!**

Comment: Ok! I didn't think to look at PowerShell. That's a great suggestion. However I don't know PowerShell very well at all. Any tips on how I would go about implementing this on PowerShell?

Comment: Google? i'm not that familiar with PowerShell myself, I'm more about C#

Comment: Website logins can also be done using [XMLHttpRequests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17709306/1630171) in VBScript. However, depending on what the actual purpose of this login is, you may need something more advanced (e.g. [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Powershell.

Here is an example for getting the window name, it should be possible to use it to detect Internet explorer to.

```
$selectedWindows = get-process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -match "Editor"}
```

in $selectedWindows there are all windows which title matches "Editor"

Now you can get the $selectedWindows in front and use sendKeys to work with the Window.

For getting the Window activated and in front i have a short example here:

http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/22992037